# Should iOS app logins count toward streak badges?

Tags: support, ios-app, activity-badges

I recently went away on a trip without my computer. I had a 51 day streak on Spanish Stack Exchange, about half way to my first gold badge.

Realizing that the streak would go away without a login, I downloaded the app, signed in to my account, went on Spanish Stack Exchange and voted a couple of answers up and down to keep the streak going.

When I returned home to my computer, I found out that the streak was gone. I researched this but only found a similar question about the Android app. Is there a way to fix this for the iOS app?

Answer (score 2):

The answer is the same for the iOS app and the Android app: activity there is counted towards the Enthousiast and Fanatic badge.

I think you forgot to log in one day (Note that the time zone is UTC, so that might cause some time difference when the day start is calculated)